# Copy and Paste chart into body of email VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I am attempting to add a chart into the body of my email using `GetInspector` and `WordEditor`.

I am having difficulty simultaneously adding text into the body as well.  Based on the paragraph position I choose, I can either have the text appear or the chart, but not both at the same time.

Code sample:

```
Sub generateEmail()
Dim OutApp as Object
Dim OutMail as Object
Dim filePath as String
Dim cht as ChartObject
Dim vInspector as Object
Dim wEditor as Object

Set cht = wsData.ChartObjects("Chart 2")
cht.copy

With wsHome
filePath = ""
'also including an attachment which is working fine
End With

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

Set vInspector = OutMail.GetInspector
Set wEditor = vInspector.WordEditor

On Error Resume Next

With OutMail
.to = "All"
.CC = ""
.BCC = ""
.Subject = "Test"
.display
wEditor.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text = "Please see attached"
wEditor.Paragraphs(2).Range.Paste
'if I comment out paragraph 1 and change the second line to paragraph 1
'the chart prints perfectly, but the text does not show
'the way its set up now, only the "Please see attached" shows up

.Attachments.Add (filePath)
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

I'm definitely missing something with the way paragraphs are read with the `wordEditor`, but have not used it enough to troubleshoot effectively.

Answer (score 1):

`On Error Resume Next` *hides* the error that is occurring. Remove it and you'll get

> Run-time error '5941': The requested member of the collection doesn't exist.

The email body only has 1 paragraph; you can't paste into paragraph 2 because it doesn't exist. Maybe `Add` a 2nd paragraph and then paste:

```
wEditor.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text = "Please see attached"
wEditor.Paragraphs.Add
wEditor.Paragraphs(2).Range.Paste
```

Comment: That did it, thank you!  I'll have to remember in the future to comment out the on error resume next until I have it working the way I need!

Comment: Even better, avoid using `On Error Resume Next` and instead handle errors that may occur.